# symfony2 cookie created after page load

Tags: symfony, templates, cookies, header

I am trying to execute and then display a cookie in my nav header template.

Currently my controller checks if a user is logged in.  If not logged in then checks for a cookie.  If no cookie exists a generic cookie is created.   And then finally the template is loaded.

Currently the cookie is being created and template is loaded just fine, but the value passed when rendering the template does not show up after the page loads.  I can see the cookie is created, and if I reload the page a 2nd time everything works as intended.

So I know this means the headers are not being sent as expected correct?  But I cannot figure out the proper way to do this in Symfony2.

Here is my controller code:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;

class navController extends Controller {

    public function displayNavAction() {


        $userState = '';
        $userZipcode = '';

        if ($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken() != null) {
            // To check if user is authenticated or anonymous
            if ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') === true) {
                $user =  $this->getUser();
                $userCity = $user->getCity();
                $userState = $user->getState();
                $userZipcode = $user->getZipcode();
            } else {
                //User is not logged in, so check for cookie.

                $request = $this->get('request');
                $cookies = $request->cookies;

                if ($cookies->has('city'))
                {
                    //User not logged in, but cookie exists.  So use cookie.
                    $userCity = $cookies->get('city');

                } else {
                    //User not logged in, and no existing cookie.  So create cookie.
                    $cookieGuest = array(
                        'name'  => 'city',
                        'value' => 'seattle',
                        'path'  => '/',
                        'time'  => time() + 3600 * 24 * 7,
                        false,
                        false
                        );

                    $cookie = new Cookie($cookieGuest['name'], $cookieGuest['value'], $cookieGuest['time'], $cookieGuest['path']);
                    $response = new Response();
                    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
                    $response->sendHeaders();

                    $userCity = $cookies->get('city');
                }


            }
        }


        return $this->render(
            'trrsywxBundle:Default:nav.html.twig', array('city' => $userCity, 'state' => $userState, 'zipcode' => $userZipcode, 'tempjunk' => $userCity));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the response you created that's the problem try this :

```
  $userCity = $cookies->get('city');
  $response = new Response($this->render(
         'trrsywxBundle:Default:nav.html.twig',array(
              'city' => $userCity,
              'state' => $userState,
              'zipcode' => $userZipcode,
              'tempjunk' => $userCity
     )));

 $cookie = new Cookie($cookieGuest['name'], $cookieGuest['value'],$cookieGuest['time'], $cookieGuest['path']);
 $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
 $response->sendHeaders();


 return $response;
```

then you can get cookie value in your twig using the request global {% app.request.cookies %}